# react nativeで撮影した / 選択した 画像そのものを反転させるには？

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

#### 前提・実現したいこと

他のサイトでも同じ質問をしております。よろしくお願いいたします。

react native で ImagePicker.showImagePicker から 選択、撮影した『画像そのもの』を水平方向にを反転させたいです。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

選択、撮影した 画像を反転して『表示』させることはできますが、『画像そのもの』を水平方向に反転させる方法がわかりません。

反転させた状態で upload したいので、 表示上ではなく、画像そのものを反転させる必要があります。

選択、撮影した時点で反転させるのではなく、後から好きなタイミングで反転させることを想定しております。

#### 該当のソースコード

こちらで見た目上は反転させることができます。

```
transform: [{scaleX: -1}],
```

画像データ自体を反転させる方法がわかりません。

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/289389) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: 解像度やpixcelビット数とかの課題はあるでしょうが、表示が出来ているならそれをアップロードすれば良いのでは？ [How to upload canvas and image to the server with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48619138/9014308) いったん画面から見えない位置に変換用の高解像度？なcanvasを作るとか工夫出来そうですが。まあreactとか触れたことが無いので感覚だけで言っていますからトンチンカンなことなら聞き流してください。

Comment: ＞他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿 をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います  
追記しました。ありがとうございます。  
    
＞表示が出来ているならそれをアップロードすれば良いのでは？  
こちらでは、画像そのものは変換されていないので、反転前の画像が upload されます。

Comment: 作業用のcanvasを作って反転された状態の画像をコピーして、それをuploadするとかではどうでしょう？

Comment: >作業用のcanvasを作って反転された状態の画像をコピーして、それをuploadするとかではどうでしょう？
canvas あまり知らないのですが、ImagePicker の response.data のようなデータは取得できるのでしょうか？

Comment: このQA記事 [【React-Native Expo】ImagePickerで選択した画像JPGをCanvasに表示する方法](https://teratail.com/questions/286243) だと難しそうですが、こちらのIssueの最後だと何か出来そうです。[How to render an image from React Native Image Picker #78](https://github.com/iddan/react-native-canvas/issues/78) まあこちらをつかうのかもしれませんが。[iddan/react-native-canvas](https://github.com/iddan/react-native-canvas)

Comment: canvas に移した後に、以下のimage.daraのような値は取得できないようではないですか？？

image: {
  data: "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQ",

Comment: この辺が応用出来そうです。[HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL), [Canvas.toDataURL() - キャンパスをデータURIに変換する](https://syncer.jp/javascript-reference/canvas-todataurl), [Canvasで描画した画像を送信してサーバに保存する](https://qiita.com/0829/items/a8c98c8f53b2e821ac94) あるいは上記にコメントしたreact-native-canvasにそんな機能はありませんか？

Comment: ＞この辺が応用出来そうです。
丁寧にありがとうございます。試させていただきます

Answer (score 0):

反転してからアップロードするのではなく、アップロードしてから反転してはどうでしょうか？サーバーサイドであれば、ImageMagickなどのツールで加工できるかと思います。

Comment: 複数枚 upload するので、反転するものとしないものがありますので、
アプリ使用者が反転させることがベストなんです。。

バックグラウンドでの処理も考えてみます。ありがとうございます